# Linkedin API - Unknown field {} in resource {Person}

Tags: c#, api, rest, linkedin-api

After hundred of tests I still cannot access information about one of my level 1 contact throught he LinkedIn API.

I always get the very annoying "Unknown field {} in resource {Person}" error.

I use OAuth2. The following request works perfectly :

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=AQW...

That one does not :

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsebastienrousset?oauth2_access_token=AQW...

- The given profile url is the public profite url of a level 1 contact
- I've seen many posts about that particular error related to slash encoding => my encoding is correct.
- Yes I gave the application the default scopes basicprofile, fullprofile and network
- I did the same in the explicit scope when requesting the OAuth2 authorization.

What is the point I'm missing ?
Any help would be appreciated

Just in case, let me add a sample code

```
// works
//var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=" + tokenAccess;
// does not work
var url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fsebastienrousset?oauth2_access_token=" + tokenAccess;

// create the request
var request = (WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest);

string message;
try
{
    // now get a response
    var response = (request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse);

    message = "success";
}
catch (WebException wexc)
{
     // returned status code is 400 (BadRequest)
     message = "failure - HTTP " + ((HttpWebResponse)wexc.Response).StatusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is : put this into your web.config

```
<uri>
  <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
    <add name="https" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
  </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

The .Net framework added an additionnal security on URI parsing that escapes the slashes.
That's why my request could ended as a BadRequest for the linkedin API.